Is there a known generalized Fermat prime with exponent at least $2^{21}$?
In OEIS , the smallest even positive integers $k$ such that $k^{2^n}+1$ is prime are given upto $n=20$.

Is there a known prime number with $n\ge 21$ ? Such a number would be very large , so I guess there is no known case. In this case , how far have the numbers be proven to be composite for $n=21$ and $n=22$ ?


In particular : Is $$2024^{2^{22}}+1$$ prime ?

Is this a contest math problem?

That would be a coincidence. I am personally interested in this number since I did not find a prime factor of it.

@Peter -- Fermat prime or Fermat number? In the caption you write Fermat prime

Comment:
We want to see  $a=2024^{2^{22}}+1$ is prime.We have:
$2^{22}\equiv 4\bmod 10\Rightarrow 2024^{2^{22}}\equiv 6\bmod 10 $
Therefore:
$a=2024^{2^{22}}+1\equiv 7 \bmod 10$
Now consider following sequence of twins:
$(5, 7), (15, 17), (35, 37), (45, 47), (65, 67), (95, 97), (105, 107), (125, 127), (135, 137),(155, 157), (165, 167)\cdot\cdot\cdot$
So if $a$ is prime then it must be a member of this sequence. If the dustance between twins is $d$, the coresponding distances are:
$d=10, 20, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 10, 20, 10, \cdot\cdot\cdot$
As the numbers become larger the distances become larger too. If we find a pattern may be we can define $a$ is a member of this sequence or not.
Now we may write:
$2^{22}\equiv 4 \bmod 10\Rightarrow 2^{22}+1\equiv 5 \bmod 10$
That is $2^{22}+1$ is a composite and also a multiple 0f $5$. If $q=2^{22}+1$ is a Charmichael number , then we may write:
$2024^{2^{22}}+1=2024^{q-1}+1\equiv 2\bmod (q=2^{22}+1)=m(2^{22}+1)+2\equiv 7\bmod 10\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$
Which means $m$ must be a multiple of $5$.But $q$ is also a multiple of $5$, that is we have $a=25 t+2$. But primes in the sequence cannot be of this form; they are of the form $5s+2$ , where $s$ is odd and also s is not a multiple of $5$ . That is  probably $a$ is not prime, if $q$ is a Charmichael number.If $q$ is not a Charmichael number then relation (1) does not hold which contradicts the form of primes in the sequence i.e $a=5s+2$, which again deduces the fact that $a$ is not a prime.  In this way one way to check the primality of $a$ can be finding out whether $q=2^{22}+1$is a Charmichael number or not.

Sorry , but I cannot follow this argument at all.

@Peter, sorry for that, I tried to explain my idea in editing. This is just an idea maybe worth considering.
